# PHP read CSV file with different deliminator

Tags: php, csv

I have this simple script to read my CSV and map it into an array.
My database administrator wants to use a different deliminator. 
Is there a way to just tell PHP to split it based on a `~` instead?

```
$file="rates.csv";
$csv= file_get_contents($file);
$array = array_map("str_getcsv", explode("\n", $csv));
```

Or is there a different function that can do that for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an anonymous function so that you can pass arguments to `str_getcsv()`:

```
$array = array_map(function($v) { return str_getcsv($v, '~');  }, file($file));
```

Also, I use `file()` instead of `file_get_contents()` and `explode()`.